# Custom Validation Rules do not work for Webix Colorpicker

Tags: validation, color-picker, webix

I'm using webix as my JavaScript front end.

I've created a form with a `colorpicker` view.  In Webix, by default, the `colorpicker` only allows users to pick from a pre-selected range of colors, and returns the hex code of the color selected.

This behavior can be overridden to allow entering of any color by using the option `editable: true`.  However, `editable: true` allows users to enter anything into the `colorpicker` as if were a free text field.

I'm trying to use a custom validation to work around this.  I should be able to return false in the custom validation function to alert the user user of an invalid value and to prevent the form from being saved until it's fixed.  However, the custom validation function never gets called when used on the `colorpicker`.

Here's a webix snippet of what I'm trying:
https://snippet.webix.com/28oadxzl

```
webix.ui({
    view:"form",
    id: "theForm",
    name: "theForm",
    elements:[
        {
            view:"colorpicker",
            label:"color",
            name:"color",
            id: "color",
            editable: true,
            validate: webix.rules.iscolor,
            on:  {
                onChange:  function(newv, oldv)  {
                    // this gets called every time the color picker is changed.
                    webix.message({text: "onChange: " + newv})
                    this.validate();
                }
            }
        },
        {
            view:"button",
            type:"form",
            value:"ok",
            width:200,
            align:"right",
            click: function()  {
                // this gets called when the "ok" button is clicked.
                webix.message({text: "click"});
                $$("theForm").validate();
            }
        }
    ],
    rules:  {
        iscolor:  function(value)  {
            // never gets called!  Should be called on colorpicker change and on "ok" click.
            return false;  // replace with regex hexcode validation.
            webix.message({text: "iscolor: " + value})
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost right: https://snippet.webix.com/4mw3mxk8

The thing is that:

- as a key in rules, you must use the name of the control ("color" in your case)
- webix.rules includes only predefined validation rules (isEmail, isNotEmpty, etc)